# How to delete blocks and why some you can delete and others you can't?

Tags: blocks

I'm probably missing something here....

But there is no delete option for blocks, either enabled OR dissabled.

Additionally, some blocks can be deleted, and some don't , they have the same exact settings.

[image]

Comment: Some are created in code, some are created via the Block UI etc. Those created in code as well as those created via Views cannot be deleted from that page. Only those created via the Block UI can be deleted from there.

Comment: As long as I know they have been created with node as block, block and views, but nothing created in code. Regardless, there MUST be a way to delete them? I looked in PHO myadmin, and they are not there eitjher!

Comment: Are all the block you want to delete made using nodeblock module?

Answer (score 2):

J. Reynolds is right. These blocks are generated from code. This means this block is added programmatically through [`hook_block_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7). Some modules use this to define static blocks (like the login block or the "Created with Drupal" block). However some other modules implement this hook in a dynamic way. Views for example uses this to generate a list of all blocks in all (enabled) Views.

So even though you did not create them in code. Some of the modules you use do. Only blocks you have created using the `Add block` link on `admin/structure/block` can be deleted.

In order to remove a Views block from the listing, disable the View (or the block display in the view). I have no idea how to hide a block generated from Node as block. And I suppose there is not a real way to remove these blocks from the listing without writing a custom module.

You could attempt to create a custom module and implement [`hook_block_info_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_info_alter/7), in which you unset all blocks you don't want. Maybe something like this:

```
function MYMODULE_block_info_alter(&$blocks, $theme, $code_blocks) {
  // Attempt to disable the login block by status.
  $blocks['user']['login']['status'] = 0;

  // If above doesn't work unset the block.
  // Array is built like $blocks[module][block_name]
  unset($blocks['user']['login']);

  // Disable all Views blocks (also used ones!!)
  unset($blocks['views']);
}
```

But to be honest, I doubt if it is worth the effort and it can lead to confusion in the future if expected blocks do not show up. So I'd advice just to leave it.

Answer (score 0):

As Reynolds pointed out, the blocks created via code (generally provide by modules or core via views or hook_bock_info(),  hook_block_view()) cannot be deleted and the blocks created via structure->blocks->create new block can be deleted as they reside in database.

If you want to remove the views from showing up, you can just disable them from Block UI as in most of the cases i don't think deleting a block is a necessity.
Also if you want to modify a block to suit your needs, you can use hook_block_info_alter() and hook_block_views_alter().
You can find a lot of help and simple examples on how to do it. Hope this helps.